# How to Search with multiple parameters in LINQ Where Clause

Tags: c#, linq, search, parameters, where-clause

I have a Travel Project (ASP.NET MVC4). I want to Search Tours with multiple parameters in a LINQ where clause.

This is my View:

```
<form class="green" id="formsearchtravel" method="get" action="@Url.Content("~/" + "search")">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
                        <select name="destination" >
                                <option value="any">All </option>
                                <option value="India">Ấn độ</option>
                                <option value="thailand">Thailand</option>
                                <option value="japan">Nhật bản</option>
                                <option value="uk">Anh</option>
                            </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
                       <select name="duration" >
                                <option value="any">All</option>
                                <option value="5">from 0 - 5</option>
                                <option value="10">from 05 -10</option>
                                <option value="15">from 10 -15</option>
                                <option value="16">over 15 days</option>
                            </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
                        <select name="price" >
                                <option value="any">All</option>
                                <option value="500">A – 0 – 500 $</option>
                                <option value="1000">B – 500 – 1000 $</option>
                                <option value="2000">C – 1000 – 2000 $</option>
                                <option value="3000">D – 2000 – 3000 $</option>
                                <option value="4000">E – Trên 4000 $</option>
                            </select>
                      </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
                        <input value="Search" type="submit" />
                    </div>
</form>
```

This is the Controller:

```
public IEnumerable<TourSummaryDto> GetSearchTours(string destination, int? duration, int? price)
{
        var query = _tourItemRepository.GetAll();

        return
            ConvertToTourSummaryDtoQuery(
                query.Where(p => p.Category.Name.ToUpper() == destination.ToUpper() &&  p.TourContent.Giagoc > 500 && p.TourContent.Soluongngay < 15).OrderByDescending(t => t.CreatedDate));
}
```

How to Search with `Destination = any` or `Destination = something And Duration = all` or `Duration = something AND Price = all or Price = somethings`

How to Search with all of them ( Destination and Duration and Price )

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by Destination = Any or Destination = something etc. Could you elaborate your question giving some specific example?

Comment: For example : 1, Destination  = all  AND 5 days <= Duration <= 10 days AND $500 <= Price <= $1000 ? ; Example 2: Destination  = India  AND Duration = all  AND $500 <= Price <= $1000....

Answer (score 1):

You can build up your `where` clause based on the input given.

For example:

```
public IEnumerable<TourSummaryDto> GetSearchTours(string destination, int? duration, int? price)
{
        var query = _tourItemRepository.GetAll();

        //always has a destination
        query = query.Where(p => p.Category.Name.ToUpper() == destination.ToUpper();

        //filter results that also have the given duration, only if a value is provided.
        if (duration.HasValue)
        {
            query = query.Where(p => p.Duration == duration.Value);
        }

        return
            ConvertToTourSummaryDtoQuery(query.OrderByDescending(t => t.CreatedDate));
}
```

This will obviously AND the conditions together.  If you have an OR condition (specifically, where limited to two input values) then you will need to combine them into a single `where` clause.

Comment: How to build up Where clause :  if  Duration < 5 days OR  5 days <= Duration  <= 10 days OR 10 days < Duration  <= 20 days AND $500 < Price < $1000....